# ¿Por qué el término "reflexivo" cedió paso a "pronominal"?

Tags: historia, verbo-pronominal

Cuando aprendí las bases de la gramática del español, por los finales de los años 70, con un libro publicado durante la segunda guerra mundial, se hablaba de los verbos *reflexivos*.  Ahora veo que el término moderno y preferido es "pronominal."  ¿Por qué se dio este cambio?

Answer (score 4):

Algo como «el jarrón se cayó» no es reflexivo. Lo que lo caracteriza es el hecho de que se construye con pronombre. La terminología actual es más precisa. Piensa es «la planta se secó por culpa del calor» y compáralo con «la niña se secó con la toalla». La segunda es claramente reflexiva, pues la niña se hace algo a sí misma, pero no la primera.